# Reducing two variable linear Diophantine equation to modular inversion

Tags: nt.number-theory, cryptography

I'm in the field of secure multiparty computation using Homomrphic encryption or secret sharing. I want to implement a secure protocol to compute the GCD of two encrypted numbers.

To calculate the GCD, I particularly need to be able to securely calculate the quotient of the division of two numbers. There is a secure protocol for that but is too expensive. Instead, I thought that I might use the much cheaper protocol for computing the modular inversion of an encrypted number as a building block for the GCD protocol.

Since both problems (quotient and modular inversion) can be reduced to solving a linear Diophantine equation then perhaps we can reduce one to the other:

Modular inversion $y=x^{-1} \mbox{ mod } p$:

$x y + p m = 1$

Quotient division $q=\lfloor \frac{a}{b} \rfloor$:

$ q b + (a \mbox{ mod } b) t = a$

> The question is whether we can rephrase this equation such that the right hand side is 1 (and still be a linear Diophantine), so we are able to use an existing modular inversion protocol to calculate the quotient division.

P.S.: I can't use the extended euclidean algorithm directly on any of them. The only allowed (secure) protocols to be used as building blocks are modular inversion, multiplication, modular division, and addition.

Comment: Both equations have infinitely many solution, and computing the quotient from an arbitrary solution to the latter equation will involve division. In general, we would have $t\equiv 1\pmod{b}$ but not necessarily $t=1$. And for $t\ne 1$, a division by $b$ will be required to reduce it to 1, which is not any better then simply dividing $a$ by $b$.

Comment: @Speiser: No it is not elementary. I do not want to use extended GCD. In fact, I am in the field of secure multiparty comptuation and I want to implement the GCD algorithm itself in a secure form, given only a secure protocol for modular inversion (Using homomorphic encryption or secret-sharing).
It would have been trivial to use extended GCD to solve these equations, but I don't have a secure sub-protocol for that. 

Comment: @Alekseyev: Thanks for your useful comment. So since it is not possible I'll try another research direction.

Comment: In the future, you should probably include that kind of information with the original question.  It looked a lot like an elementary question.

Comment: @Yuan: Thanks for the hint. I do apologize for the readers who were mislead by this mistake; I am new to online community discussion and the line between not too long and too less information was still a bit fuzzy to me. I just was trying to be nice and write as short as I can so as not to waste the time of the reader.

Comment: Can you specify which homomorphic encryption scheme you want to use? Also, the modular inversion, do you mean a scheme that receives an encrypted pair $(x,p)$ and transforms the cipher text to $x^{-1} mod p$?

Comment: I can use Paillier or its generalized variant[1].For the inversion protocol I am using the idea in of [2, Section 3] after porting it to Paillier as it was based on secret sharing (because I can't do secret sharing multiplication in two-party setting (see http://bit.ly/9tuXPf)). In general, it's a protocol where the modulus (a mod b in our case) is public.

[1] I. Damgård and M. Jurik, "A Generalisation, a Simplification and ....," Public Key Cryptography, 2001, pp. 119-136.

[2] J. Bar-Ilan and D. Beaver, "Non-Cryptographic Fault-Tolerant Computing ....," PODC'89, Edmonton